# How to drag and resize two QTextEdit side by side of each other?

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I created two QTextEdit box side by side of each other in a horizontal layout (in Qt Designer). I'd like to be able to drag and resize them accordingly. However I can't seem to find the handle between them to drag, please help. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select both `QTextEdit` widgets (click the first, then Ctrl+Click the other.) Then right-click and select "Layout->Layout horizontally in Splitter."

The result will be a layout that contains both widgets, separated with a splitter. You can select the splitter itself in the right side-panel (where you see all objects), and you can edit the `QSplitter` properties there.

And finally, the place where this was documented is here:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html

(In the "Splitter Layouts" section.)

Comment: I did this Select both QTextEdit widgets (click the first, then Ctrl+Click the other.) Then right-click and select "Layout->Layout horizontally in Splitter." but the Layout horizontally in Splitter is grayed out. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: @YeP You need to break any existing layouts first. There's a button for this at the top (just below the menu bar). It's a row of button for various layouts. The "break layout" button is the second-to-last of those. Select each QTextEdit widget and click the "break layout" button. Then you should be able to create the splitter layout. And before you ask: yes, Qt Designer is very finicky when it comes to layouts. You sometimes need to break existing layouts and then create them again. It's a bit annoying, but I got used to it :-P

Comment: Great, thanks for the help. It took me a while to get everything right after breaking the layout, but i made it work! Thanks!